# BarBackgroundColor not working in a Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

On line 20 below, I am trying to set the BarBackgroundColor in a Xamarin Forms app to a blue shade with the rgb values of 0 69 140...

[image]

The 0 69 140 color should result in...

[Google Color Picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=rgb%200%2069%20140&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&oq=rgb%200%2069%20140&aqs=chrome..69i57.392j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
[image]

But instead the background color in the app looks like...

[image]

Can someone see what I am doing wrong, and how to change the color to match the desired blue?  The same color results on the Android side as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.color.-ctor?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Color__ctor_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_), you will see that the constructor

```
public Color (double r, double g, double b);
```

clamps the values between [0..1]

Instead you should use the `FromRGB` static method

```
var color = Color.FromRGB(0, 69, 140);
```

which takes int args in the [0-255] range

Comment: Just found that myself.  I should have looked there first, and thanks!